# detecting if someone has selinux installed / httpd_can_network_connect enabled

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, selinux

When SELinux is installed there's a setting - httpd_can_network_connect - that often prevents PHP's fsockopen() from making outbound connections when it was instantiated by a request coming in via HTTP.

I would like to be able to see, via PHP, if a system has SELinux / httpd_can_network_connect enabled. If so I'd present the user with a warning saying that this setting could interfere with the page.

I installed SELinux on an Ubuntu machine and altho httpd_can_network_connect [doesn't even appear to be an option that's available](https://superuser.com/q/915464/172193) to me SELinux none-the-less does appear to be installed and I'm not seeing any indications of it installed even in the phpinfo() output..

Any ideas?

Comment: The link you added after my answer works fine for me with getsebool on CentOS.  Is my solution not one you were looking for?  The only selinux integration with PHP is a pecl package afaik.

Comment: It works but on hosts that have SELinux installed functions like `exec` or `shell_exec` might be disabled as well.

Answer (score 5):

Not sure about selinux integration with PHP.  You could use the shell command.

```
$getenforce = trim(shell_exec("getenforce"));
if ($getenforce == "Disabled" or $getenforce == "Permissive") {
    // good to go
}
```

Although, getenforce may not exist on all Linux systems, so you may want to test the function somehow.  Here is something that may work for that:

```
exec("getenforce", $getenforce, $return);
if ($return or ($getenforce[0] == "Disabled" or $getenforce[0] == "Permissive")) {
    // good to go
}
```

As the return value should be greater than 0 if the user either doesn't have access to or the getenforce command doesn't exist.

> Note:  On my system, getenforce is in /usr/sbin, so you may need to
>   specify the full path to getenforce if sbin isn't in the user's include path. 
>   There appear to be no restrictions on non-superusers running
>   getenforce from my testing.

Answer (score 2):

There are some php bindings for the libselinux userspace library that allows you (among other things) to get selinux booleans. See [php-pecl-selinux](http://koji.fedoraproject.org/koji/packageinfo?packageID=7917) in the fedora project packages archive. Here is the [pecl page](http://pecl.php.net/package/selinux).

Among other things it defines the `selinux_get_boolean_active` function which should do the job for you, it takes the boolean name and returns a `long` or -1 on failure.

There is not much documentation online but you can refer to the libselinux man pages and [summary](http://selinuxproject.org/page/LibselinuxAPISummary) for function signatures.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question: `getsebool httpd_can_network_connect`. This will retrieve the status of the boolean in question.